# Why < '(Int) ->Int' is not convertible to 'Int' > error is returned by xcode but not in playground?

Tags: xcode, swift

This Swift `function`:

```
func myfakefunc(myfakeParameter: Int) ->Int {
  return myfakeParameter
}

var itWorks: Int = myfakefunc(1)
println(itWorks)
```

won't build in an **xCode** project because `'(Int) ->Int' is not convertible to 'Int'` (error on line 5),

the same code in playground returns no error.

Why?

Comment: Another excellent example of why playgrounds are bad. A real Swift file has very strict rules about what can appear where and a playground does not obey those rules. To prepare in a playground is to prepare for failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are declaring `itWorks` globally and assigning a value to it so you can do it something like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var itWorks : Int = Int()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    itWorks = myfakefunc(1)
    println(itWorks)
}

func myfakefunc(myfakeParameter: Int) ->Int {
    return myfakeParameter
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is totally useful. Would you do it another way? (different from mine, I can argue it when you say "if you want to do so...")

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error from not declaring my function as static. Compiler was not very helpful

`extension Int
{
    static func randomIntWithMax(max :UInt32) -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(max))
    }
}`